# How to use Chrome and Apple's Screen time parental controls set to 'Allowed Websites Only'?

Tags: screen-time

Setting screen time: Content & Privacy: Content: Web Content to 'Allowed Websites Only' results in frequent prompts for Chrome Helper to access specific IP addresses.  Granting for various sites doesn't last, as following visits generate more.

The prompts appear as "Google Chrome Helper attempted to access these secure websites" and then a list of IP addresses such as https://1.234.56.789

I was expecting I would navigate to example.com and be prompted to add a rule for example.com.